# How to only allow a specific element type as children using Flow and React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm trying to reproduce the steps on Flow docs regarding specifying element type of the children prop. The example is on the official [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/children/#toc-only-allowing-a-specific-element-type-as-children).

I'm currently testing this on a react native environment, using:

- React Native (0.55.4)
- React (16.3.1)
- Flow (0.72.0)

The code I'm testing is:

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})

const Item = () => <Text>Item</Text>

type Props = {
  children: React.ChildrenArray<React.Element<typeof Item>>,
}

const Container = (props: Props) => <View>{props.children}</View>

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Container>
      <Item />
      <View />
    </Container>
  </View>
)
```

Expected behavior: get an error from flow because I'm using a `View` component inside the `Container` component, but I'm not receiving any error back.

I've also tried an equivalent version using only React on the [try flow website](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H3164AduWIBJQjTYBeMAAoAlGEkA+MAB5yOUgKViJq4Bq1L0hAJ44aYAAosclaQG9UYMPQAWGGABMuAgFzU3IQAdADCHt6+AIL4+KSmqrQMIQCiMBI0AoSqZhZwUGC6WEpKADSoAL58gsJgoYKEpBgCNPiKsji25AE2cHYKympeGABuSg6dfeTB7p4+mRX6w2PoNAAeeERgXjRQpACuMMTyiioyzkOjxi4uqvVZTS341ze3RWDAL6+q758X34ZtAAVdbZAyabT-NTAe6NZqtJQAbguSyuqDkQA), but I also receive no error back from flow:

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react'

const Item = () => <span>Item</span>

type Props = {
  children: React.ChildrenArray<React.Element<typeof Item>>,
}

const Container = (props: Props) => <div>{props.children}</div>

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Container>
      <Item />
      <Item />
      <span>Text</span>
    </Container>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Seems that flow website crashes because of `<div>{props.children}</div>`.  [Here it works as expected](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQduEAdqvAJIxakC8cYxMOh4A+OAB5UYZMxGdu4gPRSZIhjACeYLHAAKg4XADedOHFwALYABsAJpWYAuTFRgA6AMJW7DgIJQoZA1xbDx3AFFrbixmGHFNbQgCOHkQEREAGjoAX3pGFjY4DxYYZGBmLCg4PgAKAQghZ30G1ABKarFxW2AANxFmJW6+vPFi2LKKqDUzcVSRI0UkN2XERWylOdMJFVkARiUdtSUx0vLKkRogA)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems to work using "Container" as a class component

[Try Flow website example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQduEAdqvAJIxakC8cYxMOh4A+OAB5UYZMxGdu4gPRSZIhjACeYLHAAKg4XADedOHFwALYABsAJpWYAuTFRgA6AMJW7DgIJQoZA1xbDx3AFFrbixmGHFNbQgCOHkQEREAGjoAX3pGazR0DxYYZGBmLCg4LAAPLmZbdFD8TxJICtjxfQghMSNshkVFJlZ4Ytiyiqq+AAoBHtRnbqEASjhRCVtgADcRI3mhN0sbexjspS3dvPFx0vLKtTNxVL3FJDcPxEVzxRfTCRUsgAjEpAWolLdJg8aEA)